# how to retrieve information in my edit page

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

I want to retrieve the information for the edition of my article but I come across an error
My controller

```
   public function show($id){
   return new PostResource(post::where('id',$id)->findOrFail($id));
    }
```

#### myedit.vue

```
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                form: new Form({
                    id: '',
                    title: '',
                })
            }
        },

        methods:{
            updateItem() {
                this.form.put('/api/orders/posts/' + this.form.id) 
            ....
        },
       created(){
axios.get(`/api/orders/posts/${id}`).then(({data}) => this.form.fill(data));
        }
    }
```

#### I have this error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: id is not defined"

found in

---> <UpdatePage> at resources/js/components/user/orders/post/Updatepage.vue
       <Root> app.js:112186:15
ReferenceError: "id is not defined"
```

Comment: From where `${id}` is coming? Is it coming from router `params` or else?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
axios.get(`/api/orders/posts/${this.$router.params.id}`).then(({data}) => this.form.fill(data.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to replace that line

```
axios.get(`/api/orders/posts/${id}`).then(({data}) => this.form.fill(data));
```

By that

```
axios.get(`/api/orders/posts/${this.$router.params.id}`).then(({data}) => this.form.fill(data));
```

It will look for an `id` route parameter (you must change the name of that parameter if you set an other name than `id`. I would also call that from `mounted` instead of `created` (`mounted` is run before and will avoid to see an empty form).

Moreover, in your controller, you could write a simpler form of your code :

```
public function show($id){
   return new PostResource(post::findOrFail($id));
}
```

Or even

```
public function show(post $post){
   return new PostResource($post);
}
```

If the right configuration is set.

Let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: I tried it I get this error : ``` [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: router is not defined" ```

Comment: Sorry, here is the corrected code line you should write : `axios.get(/api/orders/posts/${this.$router.params.id}).then(({data}) => this.form.fill(data));`

Comment: Thanks `axios.get(/api/orders/posts/${this.$router.params.id}).then(({data}) => this.form.fill(data.data));`

Comment: I updated my answer, if it fixed your issue, could you set that answer as valid please ? this will help the other developers with the same problem to identify the right one.